# Is it bad practice to use version numbers in plugin folder names in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a Wordpress plugin that I don't want to release to the Wordpress store. Is there any issue in having the version of the plugin in the plugin folder itself?

For example, my plugin is called 'myplugin-1.3.3' and that is the folder that goes into `wp-content/plugins`.

This seems to be working well because it means that when I upgrade to a new version of this plugin, I can deactivate the old one and if there are any issues, I can re-enable the old one.

I have never seen anyone do anything like this so not sure if it is a bad practice. Previously when updating, I would take a copy of the plugin directory and move it outside of the `wp-content/plugins` directory so that if I needed to rollback, I could..however this usually means I need cPanel or FTP/SSH access.

Comment: What if you just try using versioning control software ? ( git, svn, etc ) ? The primary purpose of those software's is to control previous version ( code state ) of code.

Let's say you have the following code `echo "Hello";` versioned in `tag` `0.0.1`. Then two days laiter you like to change it to `echo "Hello World";` and add it the `version tag`, `0.0.2`. Then you think that the version `0.0.2` is not what you need, and then you can go back to `0.0.1` with just few commands ( actually 1 command )

Comment: Also note, in this case, you don't have to expose your code version in your plugin folder, as well, the move between the versions it is happening in real time, with no plugin activation / de-activation, etc. Also, I suppose, that you cannot have two plugins with the same name ( plugin name it is defined in the main plugin name, not in the folder ) in a single WordPress installation, thus you will have again to delete the previous folder.